# custom hook and private route in React immediately navigates to login

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a very straight forward private Route in React:

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const auth = useAuth();

  return auth ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}
```

and this is my custom hook:

```
export default function useAuth() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = Cookies.get("token");
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/auth`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.status === 200) {
          setLoggedIn(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  return loggedIn;
}
```

The hook successfully returns true or false, but at the time when the `PrivateRoute` is called, it is false, thus I land on the login page.

How can I wait for the hook before redirecting to login?

I call the PrivateRoute like this:

```
<Route
  path="/admin"
  exact
  element={
    <PrivateRoute>
      <Admin />
    </PrivateRoute>
  }
/>
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial `loggedIn` state value matches the unauthenticated state. Use an indeterminant value that doesn't match either the confirmed authenticated/unauthenticated status. Check for this indeterminant value and conditionally render null or some loading indicator.

```
export default function useAuth() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(); // <-- undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = Cookies.get("token");
    axios
      .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/auth`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((result) => {
        setLoggedIn(result.status === 200);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        setLoggedIn(false);
      });
  }, []);

  return loggedIn;
}
```

...

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth === undefined) return null; // or loading spinner/etc...

  return auth
    ? children
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
}
```

Comment: This is working for successful login but for unsuccessful login it is not showing anything.

Comment: @PeterPan Did you catch setting `loggedIn` to false in the `.catch` block? What is the value of `response.status` during unsuccessful logins?